# Chrome hides SPAN if "list-style-type" is "none"

Tags: html, google-chrome, html-lists

There seems to be a bug in chrome. I would like to make Chrome display this jsFiddle as Firefox does, without changing the HTML structure:

http://jsfiddle.net/qd9vcv66/

```
#linklist .icon {   padding-left:15px; height:13px; margin-right:3px;border:solid 2px red; }

#linklist li { margin-left:20px; list-style-type:none; }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="linklist">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.link1.com"><span class="icon"></span>Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.link2.com"><span class="icon"></span>Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.link3.com"><span class="icon"></span>Link 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

In Chrome, the red boxes only disappear if "list-style-type" is set to "none", which is important for me.

Comment: What do you actually want to do. Show icons or not?

Comment: Add `display:inline-block` to span in your CSS

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/qd9vcv66/3/

Comment: @abhitalks I want to show them. Thanks to "anpsmn", too. There is no other solution than "inline-block", I guess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution suggested in the comments ("display:inline-block") is good, but steals one pixel line from the icons, could not fix that.

So here's my solution now: I removed all those "list-style-type:none" lines and set the color of the LI elements to "rgba(0,0,0,0.0)" as to hide the bullets etc.

IE doesn't like that but that's no problem, I solved that with an extra CSS sheet consisting of one line appended conditionally through JavaScript.